# How to load a file across the network and handle it as a String

Tags: java, swing, url, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I would like to display the contents of the url in a JTextArea. I have a url that points to an XML file, I just want to display the contents of the file in JTextArea. how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send HTTP request in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that way:

```
final URL myUrl= new URL("http://www.example.com/file.xml");
final InputStream in= myUrl.openStream();

final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE_WHY_NOT_1024];

try {
   for (int ctr; (ctr = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
       out.append(new String(buffer, 0, ctr));
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   // you may want to handle the Exception. Here this is just an example:
   throw new RuntimeException("Cannot convert stream to string", e);
}

final String yourFileAsAString = out.toString();
```

Then the content of your file is stored in the `String` called `yourFileAsAString`.

You can insert it in your `JTextArea` using [JTextArea.insert(yourFileAsAString, pos)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) or append it using `JTextArea.append(yourFileAsAString)`. 
In this last case, you can directly append the readed text to the `JTextArea` instead of using a `StringBuilder`. To do so, just remove the `StringBuilder` from the code above and modify the `for()` loop the following way:

```
for (int ctr; (ctr = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
    youJTextArea.append(new String(buffer, 0, ctr));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

better JComponent for Html contents would be [JEditorPane/JTextPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), then majority of WebSites should be displayed correctly there, or you can create own Html contents, but today Java6 supporting Html <=Html 3.2, lots of examples on this forum or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0680__JTextPane.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its HTTP URL

Open the HTTPURLConnection and [read out the content](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `java.net.URL` open resource as stream (method `openStream()`).
2. Load entire as String
3. place to your text area